# Deployment folder when npm start or ng serve in Angular 6

Tags: angular, npm-start

npm start / ng serve build and serve the angular application.

But, which folder deploy the files ?

I need to place manually a static file there. It is only for local environment.

Comment: Place your assets on the `assets` folder, alternatively you can configure `angular.json` to include files/path.

Comment: To add to the comment above, in your `angular.json` file there should be a property called `sourceRoot` which should be set to `src`. Under `src` is your `assets` folder in which you should place static files i.e. images.